# Using regular expression split lists in ANT

Tags: regex, ant, ant-contrib

Input String :- 
[abc,xyz,mnp,aox,3ds,k42]
[brf,fd3,asd,45s,tsd]

I want to print both list separately like

list 1 :-
abc
xyz
mnp
aox
3ds
k42

list 2 :- 
brf
fd3
asd
45s
tsd

Currently i am able to print only first list with the below code.

```
<propertyregex property="lists" input="${inputString}" regexp="\[(.*)\]" select="\1" casesensitive="false" global="true" />
<echo>list 1 :-</echo>
<for list="${lists}" param="gv">
   <sequential><echo>@{gv}</echo></sequential>
</for>
```

Please help me how can i resolve this issue.

Regards,
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

No need for additional libraries like antcontrib, use the builtin javascript engine (Java >= 1.6.0_06)
 with [ant script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) like that :

```
<project>

 <property name="foobar" value="[abc,xyz,mnp,aox,3ds,k42] [brf,fd3,asd,45s,tsd]"/>

 <script language="javascript">
 <![CDATA[
   var lists = project.getProperty('foobar').split(' ');
   for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
     var list = lists[i].replace('[', '').replace(']', '');
     var items = list.split(',').join().replace(/,/g, ' ') ;
     print('list ' + i + ': ' + items);
   }
 ]]>
 </script>

</project>
```

output :

```
[script] list 0: abc xyz mnp aox 3ds k42
[script] list 1: brf fd3 asd 45s tsd
```